# How to loop WOW animation time

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page and the Contents have Wow animation with different time delay. Here is my example.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="500ms">
          <h4>Air Cargo Services</h4>
          <p class="contnt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>        

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="700ms">
          <h4>Air Cargo Services</h4>
          <p class="contnt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="900ms">
          <h4>Air Cargo Services</h4>
          <p class="contnt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here it is working. But I am actually doing is, the data will be added in this div from the database. In my PHP Code, I was added only one div for appending data and this div will be looped.

```
{% for service in services %}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="500ms">
            <h4>{{ service['name'] }}</h4>
            <p>{{ str_limit(service['description'], 100) }}</p>
    </div>
</div>   {% endfor %}
```

The Problem is, While the div is looped, the WoW-delay time is 500 for every div. So every div is showing at a time. I need the exact of HTML code that Above. How to do while div is looped. Help Me.

Thank You.

Comment: Share your js code for the wow slider too please.

Comment: Last bit of question is not clear to me. What would you like to do? Do you want  a common attribute of `data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="500ms"` for all div elements or a time variety between them? So 1st slide will show for 500ms and second will show only for 1000ms etc?

Comment: @CodeMonkey I need time varient between each div.  1st slide will show for 500ms and second will show only for 1000ms and 3rd 1300 or 1500.

Comment: 2 options. 1) store the delay in your `database`. 2) hard code time delay via `javascript`

Comment: @CodeMonkey. How to Do the Second one. I am not that much familiar in Javascript.  Please Help Me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script to dynamically set timing for your slides. Please bare in mind you have to exactly match array elements in `dynamicDelay` to your `wow slider` slide count. Otherwise you'd get the default value defined to the slide.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dynamicDelay = [
    1500,
    1000,
    1200
  ];
  var fallbackValue = "500ms";

  $(".service-item.wow").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("data-wow-delay", typeof dynamicDelay[index] === 'undefined' ? fallbackValue : dynamicDelay[index] + "ms");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wow-slider-container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="500ms">
      <h4>Air Cargo Services</h4>
      <p class="contnt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="700ms">
      <h4>Air Cargo Services</h4>
      <p class="contnt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="900ms">
      <h4>Air Cargo Services</h4>
      <p class="contnt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: I have added a fallback method in case you forgot to exactly match slider numbers to the `dynamicDelay` array elements. It will automatically assign "500ms" to the slider delay.

Comment: Thank you very Much. It's cool. Working fine for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding bud. :)